# how to get large numbers as input?

Tags: c++

Hi I'm really new to c++ and I wanted to write a code which receives a number from user and sums its digits and keeps doing that until it gets a one-digit number and returns it as a result. But I noticed that when my number is large (like 15 digits long), the wrong number is stored in the variable i declared for storing user input. What do I do?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;

int get_sum(long x) {
    cout << x<<endl;
    if (x < 10) {
        return x;
    }
    else {
        string num_in_str = to_string(x);
        long result=0;
        for (int i = 0; i < num_in_str.size(); i++) {
            int digit = num_in_str[i] - '0';
            result += digit;
        }
        return get_sum(result);

    }
}
int main()
{
    long input;
    cin >> input;
    int final_result = get_sum(input);``
    cout << final_result;

}
```

Comment: `long long` ought to do it, if you're on a 64-bit platform.

Comment: Why settle for ought to? [`int_least64_t` from <cstdint>](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/integer) will give you 64 bits or die trying.

Comment: @user4581301, That was just a poor choice of words.  `long long` *will* do it, if you're on a 64-bit platform.

Comment: @SidS  You have the right of it. As of C++11, `long long` guarantees 64 bits,

Comment: Note that your sum can still overflow regardless of the integer data type you choose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh I found out. I had to use **uint64_t** data type

Comment: Note: It's probably going to exist, but `uint64_t` is optional.

Answer (score 1):

Integer data types in C++ can store numbers up to certain limit. In particular, depending on platform and compiler, "long" can be 32 or 64 bit, and store up to 2^31-1 or 2^63-1. If you want to process numbers of an arbitrary precision, I'd suggest to read each input as string, and process it character-by character, like this:

```
#include <cctype>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::string s; 
    while (std::getline(std::cin, s)) {
        // parse string
        long sum = 0;
        for (std::size_t i = 0; i < s.length(); ++i) {
            if (std::isdigit(s[i]))
                sum += s[i] - '0';
            else
                break;
        }
        std::cout << sum << std::endl;
        if (sum < 10) break;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Minor niggle: `long` is at least 32 bits and no larger than `long long` Right now it's probably 32 or 64 bit, but when the 128 bit CPUs start showing up it could be 128 or 256 bits. Or still 32 bits. Crazy, huh?

Comment: if you want particular ensured length, include <cstdint> and use one of types like std::uint64_t.